# How to add selected by option in VIS network graph?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vis.js

I wanted to highlight all neighbors of the selected node (highlightNearest)

[image]

I am not able to achieve the same with javascript

[Srackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tree-vis-graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example on the [vis.js](https://visjs.org/) website demonstrates how to implement the functionality: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/exampleApplications/neighbourhoodHighlight.html

[JSFiddle link](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/static/jsfiddle.a6eacda850dfe6c88d8ea581887b67b263eb310301cdd593e76f7cabd6df4800.html)

[Codepen link](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/static/codepen.a6eacda850dfe6c88d8ea581887b67b263eb310301cdd593e76f7cabd6df4800.html)

Comment: Here they are writing custom methods for highlighting nodes. If you see vis documentation they have builtin method `visOptions(highlightNearest = true)` which we can make use of. I am able to achieve that with `R`. But with js no luck

https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/options.html

Comment: It seems you are referring to this [visNetwork](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork) R package which is a separate library built on top of vis.js. I have looked through the official [vis-network docs](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/) and was not able to find a `highlightNearest` option. It seems that unfortunately to do this in JS, currently the only way is to use a custom method.

Comment: ahh ok. my bad. Thanks